# Is it possible to use dynamic variable in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is it possible to use dynamic variable in ajax?
for example this is some of my view

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 value">
    <?= form_input(array('name' => 'jenis_anggaran_'.$index, 'id' => 'jenis_anggaran_'.$index, 'readonly' => 'readonly', 'class' => 'required form-control input-sm', 'value' => $this->input->post('jenis_anggaran_'.$index), 'title' => 'Ketik satuan disini', 'rel' => 'Satuan', 'style' => 'width : 100%;', 'placeholder' => 'Satuan')) ?> 
    <span class="red msg_jenis_anggaran_<?=$index?>" id="msg_jenis_anggaran_<?=$index?>"><?=form_error('jenis_anggaran_'.$index,' ',' ')?></span>
</div>
```

so i need to run a script when `jenis_anggaran_$index` is change?
in static variable i use this script

```
$("#propinsi_id").change(function(){
    var propinsi_id = {propinsi_id:$("#propinsi_id").val()};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "<?php echo site_url('chain/select_kota')?>",
        data: propinsi_id,
        success: function(msg){
           alert("it change");
        }
    });
});
```

so since my variable is dynamic how can i point those variable in my script?

Comment: which variable is dynamic?

Comment: You can always re-assign values to a variable.

Comment: jenis_anggaran_$index will be jenis_anggaran1,jenis_anggaran2 those variable can increase.

Answer (score -1):

If you use template literals, this work will be more simply.

like this, `` `jenis_anggaran_${index}` ``

Ref) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals